# HOWTO read mysql SELECT into bash variables, then use those variables for INSERT INTO a different table

Tags: mysql, database, bash

i am fairly new to this so please be patient, my understanding of bash however is that i can run

```
mysql --host=hostname --user=username --password=password -e "SELECT * FROM database.table;"
```

but i have less than no idea from other manuals how to get those into actual bash variables someone mentioned using

```
read a b c
    do while 
    echo "..${a}..${b}..${c}.."
```

but i fail to see how that will read them into the variables?

also on reading the varibles back in i will be doing something like

```
#>WGET $a
```

then login to mysql again and doing something like

```
LOAD DATA INFILE data.csv INTO thattable ON DUPLICATE UPDATE
```

i want to also so something like 
    INSERT INTO thattable WHERE (i just loaded the info) date = today
but because there will be multiple dates how do i do this, and yes this all needs to be bash-able php is too slow and C i want to avoid unless it's the only way,

thanks i know this is a lot!

-AW

Comment: PHP through the CLI is too slow for your needs as well?

Comment: `bash` is almost certainly the wrong language to use here. Choose one with an actual DB API. Python, Perl, Ruby, take your pick.

Comment: please if you're going to comment be constructive, yes all those languages are too slow i am talking about dealing with up to a billion records, this script literally will be constantly running via cron in the background.

and there is not 4 questions this is a scenario...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use "select ... \G", store result in a tmp file and grep for the columns.

By example:

```
mytmp=$(mktemp /tmp/mytemp.XXXXXX)

mysql --host=hostname --user=username --password=password -e "SELECT * FROM database.table \G;" > $mytmp

column_foo=$( fgrep COLUMN_FOO $mytmp | cut -d ':' -f2-)
column_bar=$( fgrep COLUMN_BAR $mytmp | cut -d ':' -f2-)

echo $column_foo
echo $column_bar
```

**Option 2**

If the amount of columns is high store all them in a hash array:

```
mytmp=$(mktemp /tmp/mytemp.XXXXXX)

mysql --host=hostname --user=username --password=password -e "SELECT * FROM database.table \G;" | xargs -I{} echo {} > $mytmp

declare -A a
while IFS=':' read k s; do a[$k]=$s; done < $mytmp

echo ${a[COLUMN_FOO]}
echo ${a[COLUMN_BAR]}
```

Comment: thanks! thats great and answers everything really well, nice examples!

Comment: is there a way to print and then separate with a non colon character, ideally one that is never in a URL? it is filtering http/ftp/etc off the url due to the colons?

Comment: @Adam: Edited first option. Now, in both options, a colon in the data will not cause any issue, all data will be assigned. Only a colon in the column name is problematic.